# Modal boostrap data remote error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have an error appear on the console with this syntax. It doesn't take in consideration inside the script.

When I am looking the modal appear but inside the console I have this:

Thank you.

> TypeError: a is undefined

```
<anonyme>
http:///boutique/ext/javascript/bootstrap/ajax_form/bootstrap_modal_remote_url.js:2:3

console error (bootstrap_modal_remote_url.js)

    $('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(){
      $($(this).data("target")+' .modal-body').load($(this).data("remote"));
    });
```

html line:

```
<a data-banner-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#statsModal"><img src="/admin/images/icons/statistics.gif" alt="icon_statistics" title="icon_statistics" /></a>
```

Below the code and the html rendering.

script code (part of):

```
 $(function() {
    var fetchStatsUrl = '<?= addslashes($OSCOM_BannerManager->link('BannerManager&FetchStats&banners_id={{id}}')); ?>';

    $('#statsModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      var json = $.getJSON(Mustache.render(fetchStatsUrl, {id: $(e.relatedTarget).data('banner-id')}), function(data) {
        if (typeof data.labels !== 'undefined') {
          $('#statsModal .statsModalContent').html('<h4 class="modal-title">' + data.title + '</h4><div id="banner_statistics"></div><div class="text-right"><span class="label label-info">Views</span><span class="label label-danger">Clicks</span></div>');
```

html script (part of):

```
$(function() {
    var fetchStatsUrl = 'http://boutique/admin/index.php?A&Marketing%5CBannerManager&BannerManager&FetchStats&banners_id=%7B%7Bid%7D%7D';

    $('#statsModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      var json = $.getJSON(Mustache.render(fetchStatsUrl, {id: $(e.relatedTarget).data('banner-id')}), function(data) {
        if (typeof data.labels !== 'undefined') {
          $('#statsModal .statsModalContent').html('<h4 class="modal-title">' + data.title + '</h4><div id="banner_statistics"></div><div class="text-right"><span class="label label-info">Views</span><span class="label label-danger">Clicks</span></div>');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is nicely formatted, but it is still pretty difficult to understand what you need help with. Maybe it would be useful to add some context so that people might understand what you're trying to achieve. Please add an example of what the desired behavior would be.

Comment: The `<a>` tag has no data-attribute `data-remote`, so `$(this).data("remote")` would be null or undefined.

Comment: @Mikey, could you tell me how to solve this element (code element to change) ?